# Using Generalized Time in custom field

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We are looking to add a couple of date fields to our Active Directory schema in 2008 R2 to help facilitate a bit of automation. In particular adding in a `hireDate` field that is populated automatically from an import.

This all works as expected in our test environment, however I am curious if there is a way to enhance the display of this custom attribute when it comes to dates.

The `hireDate` field is set as a *Syntax* of *Generalized Time* to match the native fields such as `whenCreated`.

However, when placing a date in to `hireDate`, it formats this much different than `whenCreated` for the display

```
> $user = Get-ADUser MyUser -Properties whenCreated,hireDate
> $user

-- snip --
hireDate          : {19870301070000.0Z}
whenCreated       : 8/28/2014 12:24:42 PM
```

If I inspect the *MemberType* of these properties, they are different too even though they are both *Generalized Time*

```
$user | Get-Member -MemberType Properties

   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
hireDate          Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection hireDate {get;set;}
whenCreated       Property   System.DateTime whenCreated {get;}
```

Is there a proper way to create a custom attribute as a `DateTime` or are we limited with the way to create these attributes?

Answer (score 1):

`hireDate` is a collection. To get the actual value you need `.hireDate[0]` or `.hireDate | Select-Object -First 1`. And if PowerShell doesn't parse a Generalize-Time timestamp for you (`hireDate` isn't a standard attribute after all) you need to [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517954/1630171).

```
$fmt = "yyyyMMddHHmmss.f'Z'"
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Get-ADUser MyUser -Properties whenCreated,hireDate |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='hireDate';e={
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.hireDate[0], $fmt, $culture)
  }} -Exclude hireDate
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid all of the conversion. Even though the attribute is single-valued, it is still appearing as a collection. At this point I might as well use an existing string extension attribute and convert that to a datetime so it's at least readable right away